# Battery drain and possible brake fluid leak

Tags: battery, leak, brake-fluid

This Sunday night I left my interior light on and this morning the car didn't even open with the remote key.

My friends and I tried to start it by pushing it (I have done this before a few times and there was no problem) but it didn't start. I even felt when the clutch was engaged that the engine was spinning but for some reason it didn't start.

The other problem is that when I was braking to stop the car with the pedal, my friends that were behind me told me to stop because there were two lines of liquid coming from above the rear wheels. They didn't smell like gasoline or oil, so I suppose it was brake fluid that could have leaked because of applying to much force to the brake pedal when the vacuum servo was off.

Tomorrow Im calling the insurance to see if they can bring a starter and check what the h*** is going on.

Does any of you know what might be happening? Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I wonder if you have two separate problems here - one electrical and one brake/hydraulic.  Or the liquid could have been condensation or rainwater that had pooled somewhere.      Could also be someone's fiddled with your brakes, so check the front hoses too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the car not starting, even though the engine was spinning, if the battery is dead, there's nothing there to get any electricity to the spark plugs to get the engine going. The alternator, even though it is spinning, won't be providing any power to the electronics or ignition because it needs an amount of electricity to energize itself. In other words, the alternator needs energy to make energy ... but just enough to get it going. If your battery was completely dead, it's not there to provide the juice to get it going, and therefore your engine won't start/run (I re-realized this recently when I tried to push start my Honda Civic!).

So *what the heck* is going on? Your battery is completely dead. Car won't start. You could give your car a jump start and it would probably be fine. Better yet, if you put a charger on your battery at 2A and let it sit overnight, you'd probably find there to be nothing wrong with that end of your car.

As far as your supposed brake fluid, you would not be providing enough force to cause the problem you are talking about. Realize, with no vacuum servo to provide boost to the line pressures, there would be far less pressure there in the first place. Enough to make the brakes work, but not near enough to be as efficient as they would be with the engine running. I'd suggest the liquid you saw was more than likely condensation coming off of the car. To double check, though, I'd suggest you have the brakes thoroughly inspected before you start driving it too far. I really doubt you're going to find anything, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the battery is about to go anyway.  An overnight with a pilot light ON should normally leave enough juice to at least crank the engine.

As far as the leaking fluid go, I'd make sure the brake system is in order before I drive the car again.